# Cambiar color a una imagen en SDL (c++)

Tags: c++, imagen

Tengo un objeto en el juego donde su color depende de varias circunstancias (escenario, colisiones etc..)

El problema es que para cada situación, en la hoja de sprite tengo que agregar nuevamente el objeto con el color distinto.

¿Existe alguna forma, de codificar la imagen y decidir mediante código la paleta de colores que se desea aplicar a la imagen?

En mi código las imágenes son cargadas con SDL_image.

Comment: No se si te entiendo bien ¿quieres cambiar la paleta de colores o aplicar un filtro de color sobre la imagen?

Comment: Creo que sería un filtro de color a la imagen. (Por ejemplo así como en el juego de los iconos de Geoemtry Dash) [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.robtopx.geometryjump&hl=es]

Comment: Un filtro de color puede ser aplicado con [`SDL_SetTextureColorMod`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureColorMod), que multiplica el color de la textura facilitada por el indicado.